# How to build the following grid in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I am trying to rebuild the contacts list from my phone using React Native. The grid looks like this:

[image]

Currently I have a grid wrapper with styles `{ flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap' }` and each of the children with styles `{ width: '40%', flexGrow: 1 }`. It works fine if there is an even number of children, but when there is an odd number, the last child takes up the full width. I need that last child to float left and have the same width as others. What would be the best way to do it?

Comment: Can you add more code, what you're using to render the list and also complete styles?

Comment: @PritishVaidya I am so sorry for my long response, here is the component that renders contacts: https://github.com/pavermakov/react-native-contacts/blob/master/src/components/Body.js

Answer (score 1):

containerStyle `{ flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap' }` 
contactItemStyle `{ height: 100, width: '50%' }`
width 40% doesn't make sense since 100/2 = 50.

You can set the height of the contactItems to be anything larger than 0. 
Forget your flexGrow property on the contactItems.